# Is it possible to analyze windows core dumps with GDB?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I work on a C++ application which is supposed to work on Linux, Mac and Windows.
While there is GDB on Linux and Mac, I have to analyze Windows coredumps on a separate Windows VM with Visual Studio installed, which is not quite convenient.
Is there any possibility to analyze Windows coredumps using GDB on Linux given I have an access to build system and can adjust build parameters?

Comment: What tool-chain was used to build the MS-Windows version of the application?

Comment: @RichardCritten wmake with some custom features which are not important in this case.

Comment: If you have used gcc to compile your windows application, gdb will work out of the box ( e.g. with cygwin ). If you have used MSVC compiler, you have to add support for PDB file format. Try a look here  https://github.com/lesderid/gdb-msvc

Comment: ... and which compiler is used by wmake???

Comment: @Klaus thank you. will look into it. Compiler is MSVC.

Comment: If the compiler is MSVC you'll need the Visual Studio debugger or windbg to analyze the minidump (AFAIK).

Comment: @JesperJuhl this is how currently I do this. It is extremely inconvenient.